# Convert a three column dataframe into matrix

Tags: r

This is a continuation of the question [[Get frequency using two groupings in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29457111/get-frequency-using-two-groupings-in-a-dataframe/29457173?noredirect=1#comment47078767_29457173][1])

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
Gene    Rptname   freq
Gene1   Cha1      1
Gene1   Cha2      1
Gene1   Cha3      1
Gene1   Cha4      1
Gene2   Cha1      1
Gene2   TH1       2
Gene2   KI2       2
Gene2   Cha4      2
Gene2   Cha5      4
```

I would like to convert the dataframe into the following format

```
       Cha1  Cha2  Cha3  Cha4  Cha5  KI2  TH1

Gene1   1     1     1     1      0    0    0
Gene2   1     0     0     2      4    2    2
```

I've got a feeling this is a reshape data issue but I dont know how to reshape the data-

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do

```
xtabs(freq~., df1)
#         Rptname
#Gene    Cha1 Cha2 Cha3 Cha4 Cha5 KI2 TH1
# Gene1    1    1    1    1    0   0   0
# Gene2    1    0    0    2    4   2   2
```

Or

```
library(reshape2)
acast(df1, Gene~Rptname, value.var='freq', fill=0)
#       Cha1 Cha2 Cha3 Cha4 Cha5 KI2 TH1
#Gene1    1    1    1    1    0   0   0
#Gene2    1    0    0    2    4   2   2
```

Or use `spread` to get a 'data.frame' output

```
library(tidyr)
spread(df1, Rptname, freq, fill=0)
```

If your original dataset is 'dat', this could be also done using `table`

```
table(dat[c('Gene', 'Rptname')])
```